# How to validate DTD file?

Tags: dtd, xml

Where's the problem these two's DTD file.I did not understand following error:

```
:Character ',' is grammatically unexpected.(line on **,**)
```

Is there a valid XML instance document from these two's DTD?

**First DTD**

```
<!ELEMENT nom (#PCDATA , (nomp | prenom)*)>
<!ELEMENT nomp (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT prenom (#PCDATA)
```

**Second DTD**

```
<!ELEMENT nom ((#PCDATA | nomp) , prenom)*>
<!ELEMENT nomp (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT prenom (#PCDATA)>
```

**Error** `:Character '(' is grammatically unexpected. (line 1 second "**(**")`

Comment: Would this work for you: `<!ELEMENT nom #PCDATA (nomp*, prenom*)>`

Answer (score 0):

When you have mixed content (which is when an element may contain both character data and optionally interspersed child elements), you must declare the element a certain way. The order and the number of occurrences can't be restrained.

See the spec for more info: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-mixed-content

So your element declaration would need to be:

```
<!ELEMENT nom (#PCDATA|nomp|prenom)*>
```